# What is the best Windows Multiple Buffer Manager that supports pasting and custom shortcut keys?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for an app that would let me specify a bunch of pregenerated replies and/or strings that I'd be able to paste ideally like this:

- by assigning specific shortcut combos to specific replies/strings
- by having a generic paste key which would conveniently pop up the list of strings that can be pasted, ideally without having to touch a mouse
- preferably there would be a possibility to set a master password, in case any of the strings are actually passwords themselves

I hope you see where I'm going with this. Example usage could be:

- support center operators who wants to send canned emails or IMs
- quick unimportant password pastes
- forum signatures
- use your imagination

Of course, free and open source is preferred.

Also, I'm looking for a Windows version at the moment.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just randomly found [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php) (made by one of Lifehacker's editors) while browsing [MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com).

It's almost exactly what I was looking for (except it doesn't seem to work with pasting ssh passwords).

Edit: a much better free alternative: [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting idea, maybe a good small summer project. The only open source clipboard manager for Windows that's worth mentioning is [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/). It has a lot of good features, the clipboard sync is a pretty amazing idea, although it doesn't support password protection of the buffer - but hey, it's open source as you requested, if you have the knowledge to tweak the code then go for it!

It stores data in a sqlite database though, which you could password protect with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). Then you'd only need to authenticate once when you log in.

Another possibility is to use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com). If the people using this computer aren't fairly tech savvy, you could compile your script with AHK2EXE and that should be fine. Although if they do know their way around things they may know about disassembling and programs like ollydbg which will show the password strings in plain text.

An example:

```
!p::
InputBox, password, Enter Password,, hide
if (password == "secret")
{
    Send My Secret Text.
}
else
{
    MsgBox Access Denied.
}
return
```

or use a regular clipboard manager for standard clipboard tasks, and use AHK with a master password to store all other passwords:

```
passes =
(
SuperUser:secret
StackOverflow:secret2
Meta:secret3
Gmail:secret4
)

!p::
InputBox, password, Enter Master Password,, hide
if (password == "secret")
{
    MsgBox %passes%
}
else
{
    MsgBox Access Denied.
}
return
```

[image]

[image]

As previously stated, this is not a secure method if savvy users will be on this system, however it's fine to protect against the average user if compiled with ahk2exe. No real point since you could use one of many password managers, but it is an easy way to have them available in a few key presses. I'd recommend the Ditto and TrueCrypt method though.

Comment: I'm surprised nothing like what I've described exists yet. The 2 methods in your post are not as polished of a solution but I suppose they could work. I'll evaluate them shortly.